# who creates map in BPF

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

After reading `man bpf` and a few other sources of documentation, I was under impression that a `map` can be only created by user process. However the following small program seems to *magically* create `bpf` map:

```
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") my_map = {
        .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,
        .key_size = sizeof(u32),
        .value_size = sizeof(long),
        .max_entries = 10,
};

SEC("sockops")
int my_prog(struct bpf_sock_ops *skops)
{
   u32 key = 1;
   long *value;
   ...

   value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&my_map, &key);
   ...
   return 1;
}
```

So I load the program with the kernel's `tools/bpf/bpftool` and also verify that program is loaded:

```
$ bpftool prog show
1: sock_ops  name my_prog  tag f3a3583cdd82ae8d
        loaded_at Jan 02/18:46  uid 0
        xlated 728B  not jited  memlock 4096B

$ bpftool map show
1: array  name my_map  flags 0x0
        key 4B  value 8B  max_entries 10  memlock 4096B
```

Of course the map is empty. However, removing `bpf_map_lookup_elem` from the program results in no map being created.

**UPDATE**
I debugged it with `strace` and found that in both cases, i.e. with `bpf_map_lookup_elem` and without it, bpftool does invoke `bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, ...)` and it apparently succeeds. Then, in case of bpf_map_lookup_elem left out, I strace on `bpftool map show`, and `bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_NEXT_ID, ..)` immediately returns `ENOENT`, and it never gets to dump a map. So obviously something is not completing the map creation.

So I wonder if this is expected behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As explained by antiduh, and confirmed with your `strace` checks, `bpftool` is the user space program creating the maps in this case. It calls function `bpf_prog_load()` from libbpf (under `tools/lib/bpf/`), which in turn ends up performing the syscall. Then the program is pinned at the desired location (under a `bpf` virtual file system mount point), so that it is not unloaded when bpftool returns. Maps are not pinned.

Regarding map creation, the magic bits also take place in libbpf. When `bpf_prog_load()` is called, libbpf receives the name of the object file as an argument. `bpftool` does not ask to load *this* specific program or *that* specific map; instead, it provides the object file and libbpf has to deal with it. So the functions in libbpf parse this ELF object file, and eventually find a number of sections corresponding to maps and programs. Then it tries to load the first program.

Loading this program includes the following steps:

```
CHECK_ERR(bpf_object__create_maps(obj), err, out);
CHECK_ERR(bpf_object__relocate(obj), err, out);
CHECK_ERR(bpf_object__load_progs(obj), err, out);
```

In other words: start by creating all maps we found in the object file. Then perform map relocation (i.e. associate map index to eBPF instructions), and at last load program instructions.

So regarding your question: in both cases, with and without `bpf_map_lookup_elem()`, maps are created with a `bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, ...)` syscall. After that, relocation happens, and program instructions are adapted to point, if needed, to the newly created maps. Then once all steps are finished and the program is loaded, `bpftool` exits. The eBPF program should be pinned, and still loaded in the kernel. As far as I understand, if it *does* use the maps (if `bpf_map_lookup_elem()` was used), then maps are still referenced by a loaded program, and are kept in the kernel. On the other hand, if the program does *not* use the maps, then there is nothing more to hold them back, so the maps are destroyed when the file descriptors held by `bpftool` are closed, when `bpftool` returns.

So in the end, when `bpftool` has completed, you have a map loaded in the kernel if the program uses it, but no map if no program would rely on it. Sounds like expected behaviour in my opinion; but please do ping one way or another if you experience strange things with `bpftool`, I'm one of the guys working on the utility. One last generic observation: maps can also be pinned and remain in the kernel even if no program uses them, should one need to keep them around.

Comment: thank you for comprehensive answer! Am I correct that in order to fully unload a pinned BPF program it is sufficient to `umount /sys/fs/bpf/xxx`? Does this guarantee that the bpf blob will be removed from the memory?

Comment: You'd `rm` the pinned entry and `umount` the eBPF virtual FS. For removal: depends on whether your program is still in use, I'd say. If you attach to, e.g., TC, then pin the program, then removed pinned entry, the program should still exist and be attached until you remove the TC classifier. If you already detached the program (or if it never was attached anywhere, e.g. if you loaded it with `bpftool`) then yes, removing the entry under `/sys/fs/bpf` should be enough.

Comment: Oh I see, I guess if the program has been attached to a `cgroup` I should first detach it with `bpftool`, then delete `/sys/fs/bpf/my_pin` and finally `umount /sys/fs/bpf`

Comment: Yes I think so. Although there's no obligation to `umount` the BPF file system. Note that the order for detaching vs. unpinning does not really matter, the program is kept as long something (pinning or attach point) holds it but you could also unpin then detach.

Answer (score 5):

> I was under impression that a map can be only created by user process.

You're completely right - user programs are the ones that invoke the `bpf` system call in order to load eBPF programs and create eBPF maps.

And you did just that:

> So I load the program with tools/bpf/bpftool and ...

Your [`bpftool`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/bpf/bpftool) program is the user process that is invoking the `bpf` syscall, and thus is the user process that is creating the eBPF map.

BPF programs don't have to be unloaded when the user program that created it quits - bpftool likely uses this mechanism.

Some relevant bits [from the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html) to connect the dots:

> A user process can create multiple maps ... and access them via file descriptors.
>
> Generally, eBPF programs are loaded by the user process and automatically unloaded when the process exits.  In some cases ... the program will continue to stay alive inside the kernel even after the process that loaded the program exits.
>
> Each eBPF program is a set of instructions that is safe to run until its completion. ... During verification, the kernel increments reference counts for each of the maps that the eBPF program uses, so that the attached maps can't be removed until the program is unloaded.

Comment: thanks for comment, however it doesn't explain why leaving `bpf_map_lookup_elem` out of the BPF program does not create a map.