# BPF: owner of a map

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf

This is follow-up to [who creates map in BPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067163/who-creates-map-in-bpf) since my new question is not directly relevant that thread.

So, it seems to me that there has to be a single *point* where a BPF map is created, either it is a bpf program or a user program that loads bpf etc.

A BPF program has to know type of maps it is going to work with at compile-time, so we need:

```
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") my_map = {
...
};
```

So it means that a user program, for example `bpftool`, will initiate creation of maps found in bpf ELF sections, as was shown in [who creates map in BPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067163/who-creates-map-in-bpf) thread.

On the other hand, user application will need to add/delete entries in the map. For this to happen, it has to know map's `ID` in order to obtain get map's fd with `bpf_map_get_fd_by_id()` from `libbpf`. After that we can enjoy `bpf_map_update_elem()` and similar APIs.

On the other hand, if we declared a map section in the BPF program and do have map API in use, the map(s) will be preserved in the kernel and will be allocated IDs.

So in this case, we are going to have two maps with two different IDs: one created as a result of `bpf_prog_load()` from `bpftool`, and the other from the user application's `bpf_create_map()` (assuming that the application continues running, e.g. update maps, and does not return to shell).

There must be a way to bypass this ambiguity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not completely sure I understand your question, let me try to rephrase this.

- You load an eBPF program with `bpftool`, which creates all maps needed by the program. `bpftool` *is* a user space application, and ultimately creates maps with the `bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, …)` syscall.
- You have another user space application `foobar` that interacts with these maps, possibly by using libbpf (that in turns ends up performing `bpf(BPF_MAP_*, …)` syscalls) to look up, update or delete elements from the maps.
- As I understand it, this second application `foobar` *also* tries to create the maps. Hence you have a conflict between the maps created by `bpftool` and the one created by `foobar`.

If this is correct, the solution is “simple”: do *not* create the maps twice.

This means that you should either delete the calls to `bpf_create_map()` from your other application `foobar`, or load your programs with something else than `bpftool`. Usually, the workflow consists in having the maps described in the eBPF object file, and created by the same application that loads the program, just before loading—this is what `bpftool` does. Then the application has the file descriptor for the map and can work on it.

Alternatively, it is possible to pin the map under the BPF virtual file system (`/sys/fs/bpf/`) so that another application can retrieve the file descriptor, and also access this map. This is done with the syscall `bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET, …)` (not yet documented on the man page at this time, at least on my system).

If I am correct, using pinned maps can also allow one to reuse an already existing map when loading a new eBPF program. I believe `tc` from package iproute2 intends to do that if the map described exists and is pinned already (see file `lib/bpf.c`, but the code is not exactly easy to read). This would typically be performed at relocation time.

Maps IDs were added recently, and primarily for debug or introspection, but they may provide another way to retrieve the file descriptor to a map in your case, as you describe with `bpf_map_get_fd_by_id()`. Although you have to find a way to get the ID in the first place.

Hope this helps!